# How to add "cucumber-glue" scope to spring junit4 tests

Tags: spring-boot, junit, cucumber

I'm developing a test service for use in cucumber-spring. The service is annotated with `@Scope("cucumber-glue")` so each scenario gets a new instance of the object.

```
@Service
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
class TestService {
    ...
}
```

I want to write an integration test for this service using junit.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestServiceIT {
    @Autowired
    TestService service;
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-glue'
```

How can I register this scope in a junit4 test?